# Xamarin.UITest retrieve all element at view

Tags: c#, xamarin, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I have couple of `EditText` inputs at view. But a few of them is hidden under screen and need to scroll to see them. How can I get all `EditText` elements in my view (also this hidden under screen). 
I tried:

```
_app.Query(q => a.All().Class(EditText));
```

But returns much more elements than is visible (return 96 should be 12)
What is the proper query?

Comment: Xamarin.Android is not relevant here hence removing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [All()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.All/p/System.String/) method changes the search query to return **all** the elements instead of just the visible ones.

The query to return **just the visible** elements with the EditText class would be as follows:

```
_app.Query(x => x.Class("EditText"));
```